# Use gsub to insert a dash to two odd numbers

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I want my program to replace any pattern of two odd numbers together to enter a dash in between them

My original thought was to utilize `gsub` but,

```
num.gsub(/[13579][13579]/, '\1-\1')
```

but this just netted me to get a dash before one odd number, i.e:

```
'575'.gsub(/[13579][13579]/, '\1-\1')
#=> -5
```

I want it to output `5-7-5`. I want a number like `12457` to output as `1245-7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding grouping `'575'.gsub(/([13579])[13579]/, '\1-\1')` would output `"5-55"`, but that's still incorrect.

You can use zero-width positive lookahead like this:

```
'575'.gsub(/([13579])(?=[13579])/, '\1-')
#=> "5-7-5"
'12457'.gsub(/([13579])(?=[13579])/, '\1-')
#"1245-7"
```

Comment: Nice one, Yu. I'd think a positive look-behind would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer @YuHao's answer, but here's a way that does not use a regex:

```
def insert_dashes(str)
  str.chars
     .each_cons(2)
     .map { |i,j| (i.to_i.odd? && j.to_i.odd?) ? i+'-' : i }
     .join + str[-1]
end

insert_dashes('575')          #=> "5-7-5"
insert_dashes('12457')        #=> "1245-7"
insert_dashes('417386523792') #=> "41-7-386523-7-92"
```